# on onclick 2 same function which is disable() not working in Primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am new bee to primefaces. I have two  commandbutton say submit and show history . I want to disable these button on click of submit . i am able to do that with help of onclick functionality but it not invoking actionListner. but only  one disable button is working fine
how to do that. please help me on that

{

```
<p:commandButton id="submitBtn"  value="Submit"  ajax="false" onclick="showHistory.disable(),submitBtn.disable();"  widgetVar="submitBtn" style="margin:10px;" />
```

}

```
<p:commandButton id="showHistory"  value="show History"  widgetVar="showHistory"   ajax="false" action="#{fileController.showHistory}"
                          style="margin:10px;" />
```

later i have tried with this code as well but then actionListner is not getting invoked

```
<p:commandButton id="submitBtn"  value="Submit" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-check"  actionListener="#{fileUploadController.uploadFiles}"
                                 onclick="PF('showHistory').disable();PF('submitBtn1').disable();"  widgetVar="submitBtn1" 
                                   style="margin:10px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PF('showHistory').disable()
PF('submitBtn').disable()
```

instead of

```
showHistory.disable()
submitBtn.disable()
```

Comment: I have tried it , it is disabling both button but then  actionListener is not getting invoked. it is not processing further .... {

Comment: Try `onstart=` instead of  `onclick=`

Answer (score 0):

Your button won't work because disabled components are not processed in the JSF request processing lifecycle. What is happening in your case is:

1. User clicks button
2. `onclick` event is triggered; button is disabled
3. JSF sees the button component is disabled in the view and ignores it
4. `fileUploadController.uploadFiles` is not fired

What would be ideal is a way to disable the button *after* the actionListener has been invoked, but I'm presuming what you're interested in is disabling the button immediately after the click, to prevent further form submissions.

Instead, I'll recommend the [BlockUI](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/blockUI.jsf). As an example

```
<p:commandButton id="submitBtn"  value="Submit" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-check"  actionListener="#{fileUploadController.uploadFiles}" widgetVar="submitBtn1" style="margin:10px;" />

<p:blockUI block="submitBtn" trigger="submitBtn"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved through jQuery.

```
<h:outputScript target="body">
        $("#form1\\:submitBtn").click(function(){
                $("#form1\\:submitBtn").hide();
                $("#form1\\:showHistory").hide();
                $("#form1\\:tradeDate_input").hide();
         });            
</h:outputScript>
```

As we know xhtml will create its own form id. it is append with user form id. and simple jQuery hide functionality.  It will hide the both button i.e. 'Submit' and 'Show History' when click on Submit button.